# Play Framework Running in Dev Mode

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm looking for some suggestions on how I could manage external dependencies when I want to run my Play framework based app locally.

I have a Play based application that connects to a database to look up application data. In order to run this against a specific environment, it is not a problem, but what if say I want to run this locally? With the current setup, if there is no database available, my app would just not start! I mean, without a database running my application also has no meaning as I could not do anything without data!

I'm using MongoDB as my database, so I see the following possibilities to enable running my application locally!

1. Use in memory mode from MongoDB
2. Use some sort of docker container to run a MongoDB instance locally

Is there any other possibility that is worth exploring?

Comment: you can make remote connection to mongodb.

Comment: you could also use an [ssh port forward](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) to access your remote Mongo instance locally if for some strange reason a direct remote connection is not feasible.